# Can I use my Unity Plus licence with Unity version 5.3.4p3?

Tags: unity, licensing

I had Unity 5.3.4p3 from 2 years ago, and I want to use it for my current project.

Since then, I've purchased a Unity Plus licence.

Can I use that licence to develop and publish my Unity 5.3.4p3 project?

(And what does the "p" in 5.3.4p3 even mean?)

Comment: 1. If you're going to copy-and-paste questions from another site, could you please take at least 10 seconds to read what you've pasted to make sure it's sensible? When you don't take at least that proofreading time, you're telling every other user here: "you are not worth 10 seconds of my time" - it's profoundly disrespectful and makes folks unlikely to want to invest time in answering your question. 2. If your existing two questions about Unity licensing haven't sufficiently clarified what you want to do, then **please contact Unity directly** to sort out your licence inquiries.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official Unity support site](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/205056229-Can-my-license-work-on-previous-versions-of-Unity-):

> ### Can My License Work On Previous Versions Of Unity?
>
> Unity licenses are backwards compatible. This means that for each license version, you can activate all versions prior to that release, but not newer versions.
>
> For example if you have a Unity 4.x license, you can activate any version of Unity 4, or Unity 3. 5.x licenses can be activated in all versions of Unity 5, 4 and 3.
>
> ...
>
> **Subscription licenses can be used on *all* currently released versions of Unity**. They are automatically upgraded to the latest version, so **you are able to download the version you wish** to use and activate with your subscription license.

(Emphasis added)

So yes, if you have licensed the current version of Unity, you have permission to use any prior released version of your choosing.

If you have operational questions about how to make this transition or register your licence with Unity 5.x, please contact a Unity representative - this is the type of thing they're there to help you with as a paying customer of theirs.